# Combine Cells into a String, so they are searchable with input box

Tags: excel, vba, input, multiple-columns

I am attempting to create an Excel sheet based on an already existing workbook. I can't change the format of the workbook, so I am stuck with what follows.

We are creating a system to use a hand scanner with barcodes containing staff names, for the purposes of tracking COVID testing.

Our workbook has one column for first name, one for last.

So B2 = Cluff, C2 = Aaron

How do I use an input box (for the scanner) that searches the string "Cluff, Aaron" (user input in the box, not the name specifically in the code) and returns the row with the data above?

Bonus points if it opens a new input box to enter the test UPC (another input looking for a string), and inputs into Column AA on the same row.

My knowledge of VBA is very limited.

I tried various edits to the following code:

```vb
Sub DualFind()

    Dim vFind1 As String, vFind2 As String
    Dim rFound As Range, lLoop As Long
    Dim bFound As Boolean
    Dim rLookIn1 As Range, rLookIn2 As Range

    vFind1 = InputBox("Find What: First value?", "FIND FIRST VALUE")
    If vFind1 = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    vFind2 = InputBox("Find What: Second value?", "FIND SECOND VALUE")
    If vFind2 = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    If Selection.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        Set rLookIn1 = Selection.Areas(1).Columns(1)
        Set rLookIn2 = Selection.Areas(2).Columns(1)
    Else
        Set rLookIn1 = Selection.Columns(1)
        Set rLookIn2 = Selection.Columns(2)
    End If

    Set rFound = rLookIn1.Cells(1, 1)
    For lLoop = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rLookIn1, vFind1)
        Set rFound = rLookIn1.Find(What:=vFind1, After:=rFound, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If UCase(rLookIn2.Cells(rFound.Row, 1)) = UCase(vFind2) Then
            bFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lLoop

    If bFound = True Then
        MsgBox "Match found", vbInformation, "ozgrid.com"
        Range(rFound, rLookIn2.Cells(rFound.Row, 1)).Select
    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry, no match found", vbInformation, "ozgrid.com"
    End If

End Sub
```

From what I gather, it needs two separate inputs to search the columns. I need it to search two columns with one input. I imagine you'd have to compile columns B and C into a string, and then search it based on input from the box.

Comment: Instead of attempting to combine two columns into one string, you could just use `Split` and `Trim` on the inputted name, giving you a first and last name. Then I would just use a `Variant` array - read both columns into the array, loop over the rows and if both columns match the first and last name, you've got your row match.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the input! If I get it working I'll let you know.

Comment: Or split as BigBen says and then set a filter on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this is what you were after but hopefully it will at least give you some more ideas. I've written this so that the user inputs the search name in the format [first name] [last name], e.g. Aaron Cluff. I've assumed from what you've written that the last name is found in column 2 and the first name in column 3.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim SearchName As String
    Dim UPC As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Row As Long
    Dim RowMatch As Long
    Dim ColFirstName As Integer
    Dim ColLastName As Integer
    
    ColLastName = 2
    ColFirstName = 3
    
    SearchName = InputBox("Enter search name:  e.g. Aaron Cuff", "Search")

    If SearchName = "" Then Exit Sub
    
    SearchName = Trim(SearchName)
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, ColLastName).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Row = 1 To LastRow
        If StrComp(SearchName, Trim(Cells(Row, ColFirstName)) & " " & Trim(Cells(Row, ColLastName)), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            RowMatch = Row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    If RowMatch = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Search Name: " & StrConv(SearchName, vbProperCase) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
               "No Match Found", vbInformation, "Search Result"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    UPC = InputBox("Enter Test UPC for " & StrConv(SearchName, vbProperCase) & ": ", "Input")
    
    If UPC <> "" Then
        Cells(RowMatch, "AA") = UPC
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It does what I needed! The only change I would make, is how to I account for special characters? More specifically, exclude them? I imagine its a split function, but not sure what that would look like embedded in the code above. You rock!

Comment: I should be able to update it easily enough. Can you just clarify what you mean by special characters and is that something which the user is inputting in the first input box and/or found within the name data in the spreadsheet? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure! I need it to exclude spaces, commas, periods and dashes " , . -"  just in case the names have them. Essentially, the names are in bar codes as "Cluff, Aaron" but I'd like for it to be able to process "Smith-Jones, Joy" or "Hitchcock, Alfred A." in case there are any in the roster. If that makes sense. All names are made up, accept for mine in case anyone needs to know that :P

Comment: Tbh I've been confused by mentions of bar codes and scanners. With the first input box which prompts for search name, is the value being typed in manually by someone or being input some other way? Is the value being input (in the input box) in the format "Cluff, Aaron" or could it also be input as "Aaron Cluff"? When you say you'd like it to be able to process "Hitchcock, Alfred A.", what would that name look like in the spreadsheet (e.g. would it be without the period?). Perhaps you could update your post with a detailed explanation including examples so I know how to amend the code. Thanks

Comment: Hey man, I appreciate the help. Don't worry about the last request. I can reformat the way the names are read to exclude special characters. Thanks for everything

Comment: Ok no problem. I'm glad the code was useful. I'm sure you'll be able to find the way to tailor it right. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do the staff name lookup:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, m, staffName

Set ws = Worksheets("Staff")

staffName = "Cluff, Aaron"

m = ws.Evaluate("MATCH(""" & staffName & """,A1:A1000 & "", "" &B1:B1000,0)")

If Not IsError(m) Then
    Debug.Print "Matched on row " & m
Else
    Debug.Print "No match for " & staffName
End If
```